# Can't detect any Pokémon

Tags: pokemon-go

I've tried to play Pokémon Go lately but I can't select/detect any Pokémon. I see the concentric circles but no Pokémon inside! Any idea?

Comment: Just reload the application. It's a no load glitch from so many people trying to login at once, it's a well known glitch and should be fixed probably by the next update.

Comment: If this has anything to do with location, check out the fixes listed in this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273940/how-do-i-fix-gps-not-found-failed-to-detect-location

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer for what exactly was the reason this was happening at the time this was posted, as it's been 4 months since then, but this is still a bug in the game.

Whenever I encounter this, I am able to fix it by force closing and reopening the app.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problems. I think it's a server glitch because of all the downloads. It doesn't happen for me now, but when it did, I had to sign myself in again (unusual right?) and then it would say I have absolutely no Pokemon registered in the Pokedex. just wait it out, that's what I did. I probably didn't help, but I hope it did.

Answer (score 0):

If it continues then I would recommend emailing Niantic about the issue. The game is still in it's early stages and there are a few issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing the circles where Pokemon are supposed to be, then they have spawned and the game is just being slow to download game assets.

Give the game a good few minutes to load the Pokemon's data in its entirety. If it still refuses to load, it may be worth re-installing the game and hoping that it works better.