# How do I fix "GPS not found", "failed to detect location"?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

Notes: This all happened after I caught my starter. Pokemon Go has all permissions. I'm originally from USA but am currently in Japan.

When I start Pokemon Go, at the time the Gyarados loading screen comes up an error message saying "GPS not found" shows up. When the game starts, the streets spawn and I can walk around them in game perfectly.

When I use a Poke' incense another error message appears saying "Failed to detect location".

Phone Type: Android Maxx 2, version 6.0.1, OS marshmallow

Things I've tried:

- Turning off mock locations in developer settings, it was already off.
- Reset all app preferences.
- Set location to High accuracy.
- Turn Location on and off.
- Running Google maps and street view while playing Pokemon Go.
- Download and ran GPS status and toolbox while playing Pokemon Go.
- Restarting phone.
- Reinstalling game.

**Is there a way to avoid these error messages and have Pokemon-Go function as it should?**

Any Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How much sky visibility do you have? The game requires a good GPS connection, if you are constantly in between tall buildings, you may have a poor connection.

Comment: I have great sky visibility. I mostly walk by rice fields and suburban areas.

Comment: I have checked Google Maps or Ingress right after getting 'GPS not found' in Pokemon Go, only to have my location detected without any issues. So I'm inclined to think the error message is specific to the current game code that reads gps data.

Comment: I've tried checking Google Maps, no change. I even installed Ingress just out of curiosity, which works fine. The game code is most likely the problem but given so many users have fixed this problem through the methods I've listed, there must be some way around the faulty code.

Comment: Now, it may just be that I am in Japan and they don't have Pokemon Go yet. Although, I still don't understand why I was able to download and play up to getting my starter and then start to receive these location/GPS errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason its not working is because I am in Japan and it has not been made available for Japan yet.

I was able to download and get my starter but the actual wild Pokemon are unavailable. Why it allows me to get that far, I'm not sure.

**Edit: Pokemon-Go works in Japan as of 2016/07/22
No need for anything that I had mentioned as possible solutions in the        question.**

Comment: Is this game available in India?